# Google Cloud Storage Javascript anonymous upload

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

I want to use GCS to store pictures taken by users in my Cordova app. I have a first major issue : I can't figure out how to use GCS properly for that purpose. Every usable example in the documentation ( [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples) or [there](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) for the auth process alone ) needs to give credentials from a Google account on the client side to be able to use the JSON API. I don't want that. Basically I want every people connected to my app to be able to upload freely to the wanted bucket. I thought about issuing tokens for every user of my app, etc... But first I need to be able to upload something anyhow, right ?

My current status is this :

```
    function init() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
            immediate: true
        }, initializeApi);
    }

    function initializeApi() {
        gapi.client.load('storage', 'v1').then(makeRequest);
    }

    function makeRequest() {
        var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.list({
            'project': PROJECT
        });

        request.then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
    }
```

And well, the log just gives me the error : "Error: Login Required" along with a 401 unauthorized on

```
https://content.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=PROJECT&key=apiKey
```

Well, since I provided everything I had, I guess I need some sort of authentication token. I simply didn't find anywhere how to do that.

The only lead I have would be this : [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts) and it absolutely doesn't sound like something fit for client side code.

Thanks ahead !

Comment: Have you tried the "resumable upload" trick as detailed at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs ?

Comment: I read about it, but this requires a server and I'm not currently using any server-side logic... I may be forced to, though.

Comment: Alternatively, as the same access control page points out, you **can** set predefined ACL `public-read-write` to your bucket, but then "Setting a bucket to public-read-write will allow anyone on the Internet to upload anything to your bucket. You will be responsible for this content" which seems scary to me.  Anyway, you can use `gsutil` or the Developers Console to set whatever ACL you want without any coding, if you wish.

Comment: That's right. But seems scary to me too ^^ I guess I will have to go with signed urls and use a server...